invalid BigNumber value for string
When I try to run the pin function that takes an integer, i keep getting an error

invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.7.0)

frontend code:
    const abi = [
      "function pinGem(uint256 tokenId, string memory latitude, string memory longitude) public"
    ];
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);
  
    try {
      const latitude = pinnedPosition.lat.toString();
      const longitude = pinnedPosition.lng.toString();

      const tx = await contract.pinGem(nft.tokenId, latitude, longitude);

contract:
i tried using uint256, but kept getting the same error then switched to string and still get the same error.
// Compatible with OpenZeppelin Contracts ^5.0.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

   struct Gem {
        uint256 id;
        string latitude;
        string longitude;
    }


 function pin(uint256 tokenId, string memory latitude, string memory longitude) public {
        require(ownerOf(tokenId) != address(0), "Token ID does not exist");
        pins[tokenId] = Pin(tokenId, latitude, longitude);
    }


In your case, the error suggests that the tokenId passed to the smart contract function is undefined. By implementing these steps, you should be able to resolve the invalid BigNumber value error and successfully call your smart contract function.

Verify Token ID Availability: Ensure that nft.tokenId is properly defined in your frontend code before passing it to the pinGem function.

Log Values: Before calling the contract function, log the values of tokenId, latitude, and longitude to ensure they are correctly retrieved and formatted. Here's the revised frontend code with added console logging to debug the issue:


const abi = [
  "function pinGem(uint256 tokenId, string memory latitude, string memory longitude) public"
];
const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);

try {
  const latitude = pinnedPosition.lat.toString();
  const longitude = pinnedPosition.lng.toString();

  console.log("Token ID: ", nft.tokenId); // Debugging output
  console.log("Latitude: ", latitude);    // Debugging output
  console.log("Longitude: ", longitude);  // Debugging output

  if (!nft.tokenId) {
    throw new Error('Token ID is undefined or not found.');
  }

  const tx = await contract.pinGem(nft.tokenId, latitude, longitude);
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Failed to pin gem:", error);
}


Ensure Matching Function Name: Verify that the function name in the ABI matches the one in your smart contract. From your provided code, it looks like the function in the ABI is named pinGem but your Solidity function is named pin. Ensure consistency between the names in the ABI and the Solidity contract. If they need to match and the correct function name is pinGem, your Solidity function should look like this:

// Assuming your contract extends ERC721 or similar
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

contract YourContractName is ERC721 {
    mapping(uint256 => Gem) public pins;

    struct Gem {
        uint256 id;
        string latitude;
        string longitude;
    }

    function pinGem(uint256 tokenId, string memory latitude, string memory longitude) public {
        require(ownerOf(tokenId) != address(0), "Token ID does not exist");
        pins[tokenId] = Gem(tokenId, latitude, longitude);
    }
}


I wasn’t passing token ID  thank you

Sounds good kindly accept the solution.

Done, can you help me with my latest question?
